# Install sass to React project

Tags: reactjs, sass

I want install `node-sass` to my React project but, i cant it, when i run project gives error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'style' in`

Steps for instaling sass

1. run `npm i sass-loader node-sass — save`
2. run `npm run eject` for unhidden webpack files
3. go to webpack.config.dev.js and past here this code

   ```
   {
     test: /\.scss$/,
     loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"],
     exclude: /node_modules(?!\/react-conventions)/
   ```

   },

   4. run project and crashed

[Include webpack.config.dev.js](https://jsfiddle.net/ntkh1dz0/)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adjust your rules in webpack config file as stated at [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) webpage

```
{
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: [
      // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
      'style-loader',
      // Translates CSS into CommonJS
      'css-loader',
      // Compiles Sass to CSS
      'sass-loader',
    ],
  }
```

You may need to install additional [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) and [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)

Comment: Thanks for quickly feedback, after install style-loader and css-loader and run project gives error " Module build failed: TypeError: this.getResolve is not a function "

Comment: If you are doing eject from CreateReactApp, then there is support for sass/scss I think, may be it is commented by default